# No valid iOS code signing keys found in keychain. You need to request a codesigning certificate

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

So I have build a Xamarin Forms application, that I now want to test on a physical iOS device. The debugger successfully run my program, but unfortunately I run into problems when I deploy my program on a physical iPhone.

I did the following in order to deploy my app:

1. Followed this tutorial in order to create a Free provisioning profile for my app (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=windows) (successfully runs xcode 1 view app, and installs provisioning profile on phone)
2. Switched xamarin to debug on a phyiscal device

The bundle identifier naturally matches, and I have done the following to solve the issue:

- Set the value of "CodesignEntitlements" from the .csproj to null

Still no success. I'm curious why Xamarin asks for a code signing key, while I'm still just debugging..

any help is much appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by asks for signing key? Are you getting any exceptions after that?

Comment: It utilize a signing key while debugging. I find that strange? - Anyway, I'm not getting any other exceptions.

Comment: Yes, you need a signing key even if you just want to debug on an iPhone.

Comment: Thats wierd, I remember that it was possible a half a year ago ish, to make a free provisioning profile through xCode with the same bundle identifier, and then use that to debug through Xamarin.

Comment: @JeppeChristensen Hi, Could you show a screenshot of the properties of project about bundle signinng .You need to check the [Signinng Identity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fsST.png) . If [Automatic Signing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/automatic-provisioning?tabs=macos#enabling-automatic-signing) not wirking , you can have a try with [Manual provisioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning?tabs=macos) .

Comment: I'm currently testing on a completely blank Forms application, just to get it working! Which means that everything is default. My provisioning scheme in the info.plist is set to manual provisioning, and the bundle signing identity is set to "Developer (Automatic)".
The only other option I have in signing identity is "distribution (Automatic)" - Even though I'm logged into my account.

Comment: In the "provisioning profile" option below my signing identity, it says "no matching profiles found" - This should though not be a problem I guess?

Comment: @JeppeChristensen You should keep the same with signing identity in "Developer (Automatic)" (This will be auotmatic generated).

Comment: Great... so lets summarize. Everything is updated on my mac, the latest version of xamarin studio, xCode and iOS - Running a blank xamarin forms application, followed the documentation for debugging on a physical iOS device with free provisioning in xCode -> failure.

Comment: @JeppeChristensen Okey , that's strange .Could you show the fail error here , I will check it .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After long struggling I just noticed that Automatic provisioning is not working anymore with my project but I just added Debug codesign key manually in .csproj of iOS project and I replaced "iPhone Developer" into "Apple Development: yourmail.icloud.com (XYZ12345678)" 
[You can find this identifier in Your Keychain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFiBS.png)

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you select "Remote Device" instead of "Local Device" during the build.

Answer (score 2):

- Ensure you are signed into XCode with your Apple ID

  - XCode Menu > File > Preferences > Accounts